# Integral of $\,e^x\!\sin(x)\,$ with substitution possible?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, exponential-function, substitution

In university we are currently learning about Integration by parts and with substitution and one of the Integrals we have to solve is the Integral of the function $\,e^x\!\sin(x)\,$.

From an exercise prior to this one, I know that the derivative of $\,e^x\!\big(\!\cos(x)-\sin(x)\big)$ is $\,e^x(-2)\sin(x)\,.$

So I could potentially show by differentiating the above function twice, that multiplying the second derivative with $\,-\dfrac12\,$ is the integral for $\,e^x\sin(x)\,.\,$ However we have to use Integration by parts (It is not permitted however to use some other technique that parts after integrating by parts at least once)

So the idea I came up with, after I integrated the function already once by parts and the result is

$\displaystyle\cos(x)\!\cdot\!e^x-e^x\!\cdot\!\sin(x)+\int\cos(x)\!\cdot\!e^x\mathrm dx$

to substitute $\,\cos(x)\,$ with $\,-\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{x^2}\,.$

This would result in
$\,\displaystyle\int-\dfrac32\left(\dfrac1{x^2}\!\cdot\!e^x-\dfrac1x\!\cdot\!e^x\right)\!\mathrm dx=e^x\!\left(-\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1x\right).$

Now my question is:

I can put cosine back as the identity without any problems, however, arithmetically, I could not figure out a way to show that $\,-\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1x=\sin(x)\,$ based on the substitution I've chosen for cosine.

So is it possible to substitute $\,\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1x\,$ back to $\,\sin(x)\,$ just by saying that $\,\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1x\,$ is (one of) the stem function(s) for $\,-\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{x^2}\,$ and because $\,\sin(x)\,$ is the stem function for $\,\cos(x)\,,\,$ $\dfrac32\!\cdot\!\dfrac1x\,$ can be written as $\,\sin(x)\,?$

Or would that be considered mathematically faulty?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Use TeX for math equations, pls

Comment: Can you explain why did you substitute $\frac{-3}{2x^2}$ instead of $\cos(x)$? That step seems completely out of left field and is incorrect.

Comment: stanleysearles, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus I can't. I realize now as well I messed up there. To keep it short, my idea was to substitute cos(x) with something that I could integrate so that it would substitute back to $-1.5 \times \cos x + 1.5 \times \sin x $

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus This way it adds up to the actual integral. Stupidly complicated and redundant but it was the first idea I came up with, I have always been very talented at finding ridiculously overcomplicated solutions for often the simplest problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the integration by parts we have

$u = e^x$ and $dv = \sin(x) dx$. Then, we find $du$ and $v$:

$$
\begin{align*}
u &= e^x & \quad &dv = \sin(x) \,dx \\
du &= e^x \,dx & \quad &v = -\cos(x)
\end{align*}
$$

Now, apply the integration by parts formula:

$$ \int e^x \sin(x) \,dx = -e^x \cos(x) - \int (-\cos(x)) \cdot e^x \,dx$$

Solving the new integral:

Let $u = e^x$ and $dv = -\cos(x) \,dx$. Then, we find $du$ and $v$:

$$
\begin{align*}
u &= e^x & \quad &dv = -\cos(x) \,dx \\
du &= e^x \,dx & \quad &v = -\sin(x)
\end{align*}
$$

Substitute these values into the integration by parts formula:

$$\int -\cos(x) \cdot e^x \,dx = -e^x \sin(x) - \int (-\sin(x)) \cdot e^x \,dx $$

Now, substitute this result back into the initial integration by parts formula:

$$\int e^x \sin(x) \,dx = -e^x \cos(x) + e^x \sin(x) - \int e^x \sin(x) \,dx $$

Add $\int e^x \sin(x) \,dx$ to both sides:

$$2 \int e^x \sin(x) \,dx = -e^x \cos(x) + e^x \sin(x)$$

Divide both sides by $2$:

$$ \int e^x \sin(x) \,dx = -\frac{1}{2}e^x \cos(x) + \frac{1}{2}e^x \sin(x) + C $$

where $C$ is the constant of integration.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you have studied complex variables yet, but if so, you will recognize that

$$
\begin{align}
I&=\int e^x\sin x dx \\
&= \mathcal{Im}\int e^x e^{ix} dx\\
&=\mathcal{Im}\frac{e^x e^{ix}}{1+i}\\
&=\mathcal{Im}\frac{e^x e^{ix} (1-i)}{2}\\
&=\frac{e^x (\sin x- \cos x)}{2}+\text{const.}\\
\end{align}
$$

This is somewhat simpler than substituting $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find

$$I=\int e^x \sin x dx.$$

We integrate by parts twice:, first set $u=\sin x, du = \cos x dx, v = e^x, dv = e^x dx$. Thus

\begin{align}
I&=\int e^x \sin x dx\\
&=uv - \int v du\\
&=e^x \sin x - \int e^x \cos x dx
\end{align}

Again, set $u=\cos x, du= - \sin x dx, v = e^x, dv = e^x dx.$

Thus

\begin{align}
e^x \sin x - \int e^x \cos x dx&=e^x \sin x - \bigg(e^x\cos x + \int e^x \sin x dx \bigg)\\
\end{align}

Thus

$$I=e^x\sin x - e^x \cos x -I \Rightarrow 2I = e^x \sin x - e^x \cos x \Rightarrow I = \frac{1}{2}(e^x \sin x - e^x \cos x )+ C.$$

And we are done.

Comment: It is the same of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot substitute one function of $x$ with another (because they will not be equivalent for all $x$ in the domain of integration, right?).  You would need to use another variable (like $t$), and change everything else in the integral, including the differential ($dt$) and the bounds if applicable.

As far as integrals of the form $\int e^{ax}\cos(bx) dx$, they can be directly computed without IBP by using Euler's theorem (substitute $\cos(x)$ with $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$ or $\sin(x)$ with $(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2i$).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use IBP twice.

The first time gives you,
as you have gotten,
$\text{something} + \int e^x \cos(x) dx$.

Then, apply IBP to
$\int e^x \cos(x) dx$
which will give you
$\text{something else} + \int e^x \sin(x) dx$.

From this, solve for
$\int e^x \sin(x) dx$.

Comment: IBP meaning Integration By Parts.